# php if time with random number

Tags: php, wordpress, date, random

I'm trying to echo a random date in a PHP loop, the code works for "if the post is 3 months old", then I want to get today's date, and minus the "random" number, eg will echo a date based on this number.

Everything is working, but not the $number. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php
    $post_age = date('U') - get_the_time('U');
    if($post_age >  7884000 ) { 
 ?>
    
<?php $number = 'UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5)'; ?>
    
<?php echo date('jS F', strtotime("now -'.$number.' days") ); ?>
    
<?php } else {?>

<?php } ?>
```

with function:

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You have `UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange()` in single quotes. PHP treats that as a string, not a function.

Comment: Doesn't work, causing errors.

Comment: Can you be specific as to what errors? Also, does your logic have to be so encapsulated in `<?php ?>` tags?

Comment: It's just still not working, its not generating a random number. -- It's just how I do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues that I see there which are likely causing the issue, there are two occasions where you are turning things into strings but don't want to:

for

this isn't running the function because it's between single quotes ' ' so you want to remove them

```
<?php $number   =   UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5); ?>
```

and for

You are mixing different types of quotes and so $number isn't really being called. You likely want to adjust it to something like:

```
<?php echo date('jS F', strtotime("now -".$number." days") ); ?>
```

Comment: This don't work too, it's causing unexpected 'endwhile' in my loop. :(

Comment: I don't see any other issues in the code right now (someone else can obviously correct me if I'm wrong). Could you provide more of your code and the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing strings and functions several times in your code, as James' answer says.

Also, your `UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange()` function returns an array. This cannot be written to a string.

```
<?php
$post_age = date('U') - get_the_time('U');

if($post_age > 7884000) {
    $number = fetchRandoms(0, 25, 5);
    echo date('jS F', strtotime("now -" . $number . " days") );
} else {
    // la dee da
}

function fetchRandoms($min, $max, $amt) {
    $result = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $amt; $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand($min, $max);
     }

     return $result;
}
```